# mocking python builtin datetime not working as decorator

Tags: python, testing, mocking

Why does this fail:

```
@patch.object(datetime, 'datetime', Mock(wraps=datetime.datetime))
def test(self, dt_mock):
    dt_mock.utcnow.return_value = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1)
    self.assertEqual(datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1), datetime.datetime.utcnow())

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 1201, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
TypeError: test() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

When this works just fine:

```
def test(self):
    with patch.object(datetime, 'datetime', Mock(wraps=datetime.datetime)) as dt_mock:
        dt_mock.utcnow.return_value = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1)
        self.assertEqual(datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1), datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

_patch_object in mock.py just calls the _patch class constructor, I'm at a loss as to how the mocked argument isn't being supplied to the decorated test method.

Comment: Try removing the `dt_mock` parameter?

Comment: @univerio ah you are correct. I was trying to use [this](http://blog.xelnor.net/python-mocking-datetime/) method of patching the `datetime.datetime` object, but I've never used the 3-arg form of `patch.object`, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the 3 argument form of `patch.object` does not emit the object that is being patched as an argument to the function being decorated, I'd never used that version before ;-)

From the [relevant documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-object):

> You can either call patch.object with three arguments or two
>   arguments. The three argument form takes the object to be patched, the
>   attribute name and the object to replace the attribute with.
>
> When calling with the two argument form you omit the replacement
>   object, and a mock is created for you and passed in as an extra
>   argument to the decorated function...

Fixed test:

```
@patch.object(datetime, 'datetime', Mock(wraps=datetime.datetime))
def test(self):
    datetime.datetime.utcnow.return_value = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1)
    self.assertEqual(datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1), datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

thanks @univerio for showing me the error of my ways...

Comment: I have a doubt.What do we achieve by doing this.patching original function and then calling original function?

Comment: @vks it is a toy example of how to patch datetime objects in tests, which is not trivial since it is a python builtin. usually, you would be mocking out a call to datetime.datetime.utcnow() somewhere deep in your code under test to simulate a particular instance in time.

Comment: @vks for instance, you might be testing code that computes the next billing date based on the current datetime, and you want to test that your code handles timezone changes or leapyears or something obnoxious like that.

Comment: Ok that makes sense...but why are we using `wrap` here....even without we can do all this right?

Comment: @vks not when using patch.object apparently